# Getting "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error with delete Bucket Replication operation in Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use delete bucket replication operation in Amazon s3 using rest API [1]. For this, I have implemented the AWS signature calculation class[2] and a method to call the deleteBucketReplication rest API [3]. But I'm getting 403 "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. Please find the request sending to backed here [4].

Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketDELETEreplication.html

[2] https://github.com/Biruntha/AWS_S3_Example/blob/master/src/main/java/AWSSignatureV4Generator.java
[3]https://github.com/Biruntha/AWS_S3_Example/blob/master/src/main/java/AWSV4AuthTest.java#L13

[4]

Canonical Request: DELETE

/?replication

host:testbuckkkbiru.s3.amazonaws.com

x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

x-amz-date:Tue, 09 Oct 2018 05:55:08 GMT

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

String to sign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
Tue, 09 Oct 2018 05:55:08 GMT 
20181009/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request
d9c53b745da19f10565cf77b6b11fde944354448322b85d99b7f502a363fb57e

### Signature:

e29af9cf031ac2c94a109f20fa9f8ad5b88b89686f86e32015c8b535b84fcc46

### Header:

x-amz-date = Tue, 09 Oct 2018 05:55:08 GMT

> Authorization = AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
>   Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/20181009/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=e29af9cf031ac2c94a109f20fa9f8ad5b88b89686f86e32015c8b535b84fcc46

================================

Comment: `x-amz-date:Tue, 09 Oct 2018 05:55:08 GMT` is not valid: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-date-handling.html

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I have updated the date format as in here [https://github.com/Biruntha/AWS_S3_Example/blob/master/src/main/java/AWSSignatureV4Generator.java#L307].
Now the Date header is going like this "x-amz-date:201810283T0510590Z"
But still I'm getting the "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error.